# Literally removing git repository created by Gitolite on the server

Tags: git, gitolite

I have created a repository called `foo` on a server using Gitolite. Now I am unable find out how to completely remove the repository from the server.

It says in the [official documentation](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/basic-admin.html) that you have to

> log on to the server and do the dirty deed yourself :-)

But how do I find the repository on the server? Where are the files located?

How can I prevent the files being added automatically back to `foo` when I try and remove it from `gitolite.conf` and add it back again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default location for the repositories created by gitolite is `~/repositories`. You can also try to search for your specific repository using:

```
locate <repository>
```

When you have located the repository you like to remove you need to remove it from the server which can be done by executing:

```
 rm -r <repository>
```

You also need to remove the appropriate lines from your `gitolite.conf`.

Comment: Which `~` would it be? I've created a user `git` with only git shell to access. And I certainly don't find any `~/repositories` in the admin user's `~`

Comment: It's the home directory of the user. How are you accessing the server? Through ssh? What kind of OS is the server running?

Comment: Yes. Through ssh. I'm not sure which home directory you are talking about though. And seems like I lost the connection now. I'll update as soon as I get it back.

Comment: Well you should be able to go to your home folder using by simply typing `cd` and hit enter, then you can list the contents of your folder using `ls -all`. It's hard to know the path to your home directory without knowing what OS you're running. You can try to go to `/home/git` if that's the home folder for the git user.

Comment: The reason I asked which home directory you were talking about was because I had a user account called git which was just restricted to the git shell. And by the way, I am working with Ubuntu 14.04 server. I did not have access to the directory in question and so had to delete the files with elevated privileges. Thanks for pointing out where the files are located though, I had no clue to where those where! :)